Every well-ordered set is isomorphic to a unique ordinal?

Every well-ordered set is isomorphic to an ordinal.

Proof:
This proof is a complete reasoning from Theorem 2.12 of Thomas Jech's set theory. The author omits three details in the proof related to this very class:
$$F = \{(x, \alpha) : x \in W \land W \cong \alpha \text{ for some ordinal } \alpha\}$$


Why is this even a function?
Domain of $F$ is indeed $W$.
How is it onto and one-to-one function?
Why is it order-preserving?


I have managed to show the first $3$. Why the fourth point holds?

In your notation,  is $w$ the same thing as $W$ ?

@EwanDelanoy I'm sorry.  It is $\alpha$ the ordinal that we pair $x$ with. $F$ maps from $W$ to the class of ordinals

What is your question? Your want your proof to be checked, right?

@AlexRavsky Yep. I also asked why "the fourth point holds". My proof has not been complete yet.

This sentence is poorly written: No well-ordered sets are not isomorphic to a initial segment of itself. The grammar is bad, the double negation seems wrong, and putting this altogether I'm not sure what the sentence is trying to convey.

It means: Let $W$ be a well-ordered set and $x \in W$. The isomorphism $W \cong W(x)$ is absurd.

To a unique ordinal *

Yes. I should add that in but it's a trivial consequence of lemma 3
